# On representations of a nonabelian group of order $pq$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Let $p,q$ primes number s.t. $p>q$ and let $G$ a non abelian group of order $pq$.
>
> 1) Determine all degree of irreducible representation
>
> 2) Show that $|[G,G]|=p$ (where $[G,G]=\left<ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\mid g,h\in G\right>$)
>
> 3) Show that $q$ divide $p-1$ and that $G$ has $q+\frac{p-1}{q}$ conjugacy classes.

**My answers**

1) There is of course the trivial representation of degree 1. I know that if there is $k$ irreducible representation, then $1+d_2^2+\cdot +d_k^2=pq$ where $d_i$ it the degree of the $i-$th representation, but I don't know how to apply it here.

2) Since $[G,G]$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $G$ is not abelian, $|[G,G]|\neq 1$ and thus $|[G,G]|\in\{p,q,pq\}$. Now I know that a group of order $pq$ with $p$ and $q$ prime is resoluble, and thus, if $|[G,G]|=pq,$ the group $G$ wouldn't have any subgroup $H$ s.t. $G/H$ abelian what would be a contradiction with the fact that it's resoluble (isn't it ?). And thus, $|[G,G]|\in\{p,q\}$. Now, each group of prime order is abelian, then $[G,G]$ is abelian. But how can I choos between $p$ and $q$ ?

3) I have no idea.

Comment: It might help to play with actual nonabelian groups of order $pq$, like dihedral groups (though they're a narrow class, their representations/characters are reasonable). Also, recall that any subgroup whose index is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group is normal. Then if $G$ has normal subgroups of *both* orders $p$ and $q$, $G$ would be their direct product (which is a contradiction).

Comment: **Hint:** If $G$ is a group of order $pq$ for $p$ and $q$ prime, then $G$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product of cyclic groups.

Comment: Since the degrees of irreducible representations divide the group order, $1$ and $q$ are the only possibilities. You know that there are $|G/[G,G]|=q$ of degree $1$, so the rest must have degree $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2, remark that by using Sylow theorem, the number of Sylow p-group divides q and is equal to 1 mod p. If this number is q, then it is impossible since q is not 1 mod p since $q<p$. You deduce that the P p Sylow subgroup is normal.

You have [G,G] is normal it is different of G since it's image by the quotient map G to G/[G,G] is triavial. Its cardinal is not 1 since G is not abelian. If it cardinal was q, then the intersection of [G,G] and P is trivial since their orders are relatively prime. This fact implies also that P commutes with [G,G] since the commutator of am element of P and [G,G] is contained in their intersection since they are normal. This implies that G is the product of P and [G,G]  and henceforth commutative. Contradiction.

For 3 consider $n_q$ the number of Sylow q-subgroups, you have $n_q$ divides p and $n_q$ is equal to 1 mod q. $n_q$ can't be 1 since the q Sylow subgroup Q will be normal and as above we remark that the commutator of an element of Pan Q is in their intersection so G is commutative, you deduce that G is commutative, contradiction. Thus $n_q=p$ and $p=1$ mod q. This implies that q divides $p-1$

Comment: I in fact don't understand your first remark with Sylow group. Indeed, since $[G,G]$ is normal in $G$, it's the unique sylow group of order $p$ or $q$. And even if it's $p$, since the number of $p$ sylow group is $1$, we would have that $1\mid q$ and $1\cong 1\pmod p$... Could you please give more detail for this remark (because I probably didn't understand what you mean exactly). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), Let $\chi_1,...,\chi_n$ the irreducible characters. You know that $$\chi_1^2(1)+...+\chi_n^2(1)=|G|=pq.$$
You also know that $\chi_i(1)$ must divide $pq$ for all $i$, and thus $\chi_i(1)\in \{1,p,q,pq\}$ for all $i$. Since $(pq)^2>pq$, and $p^2>pq$ you in fact get $\chi_i(1)\in \{1,q\}$, what conclude the proof.